# Terran Vs. Terran - BIO play

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Even though I have hundreds of hours in StarCraft 2, there is still one returning issue that I find difficult to solve, even through replays and other VODs or streams.

In Terran versus Terran, the outcome is often more tanks beats less tanks, or better tank micro beats more tanks. But the current game style of Terran versus Terran, is somewhat turning into mech and bio, and even pure bio, with only a few tanks. It emphasizes mobility contra a slow moving army. (statement based on the latest pro tournaments)

My issue is the composition and engagement in general. (as a BIO player)

**In TvT, versus a meching player, wouldn't it be best to emphasize
   Marauders?**

**In this, case, should the bio player focus tanks first most of all?**

**In TvT, versus a bio player, wouldn't it be best to emphasize
   Marines?**

**And in this case, wouldn't it be best to focus on the enemy Medivacs

   first?**

Comment: a meching player would have only 2 units with anti air: viking and thors, take them out and you can keep air superiority and your medivacs can pull out your troops and start harassing another base. use the mobility of the bio to pull the mach army out of position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your above questions in the scenario that you are placing forward:

- In TvT, versus a meching player, wouldn't it be best to emphasize Marauders?

It would be, but a player with a mech style will also be producing hellbats with medivacs. Marauders take quite a few hits (14 hits with no upgrades on each side) to kill Hellbats as they get no benefit to attacking light. If you went with a marauder heavy army all they have to do is kill all your marines so their medivacs can constantly heal the hellbats which will then wipe out all your marauders.

- In this, case, should the bio player focus tanks first most of all?

Completely, however they will most likely have widow mines as well and those will ruin your day much faster than the tanks do. It would be more advantageous to draw out widow mine fire (or scan into the attack) and drop marines/marauders onto the tanks.

- In TvT, versus a bio player, wouldn't it be best to emphasize Marines?

If both sides mass bio then mass marines and medivacs will be the highest DPS output in a streaming fashion. However, if you mix in a few widow mines and are able to draw them into it with their marines, you will win the engagement in the blink of an eye (spread the mines out).

- And in this case, wouldn't it be best to focus on the enemy Medivacs
  first?

If your medivac numbers are greater than your opponents you will win. Having more healing will give you the bigger advantage. So yes, targeting enemy medivacs will be a good thing.

It also depends on if you are attacking or defending. In my above example, you may be attacking, but you can draw them into the fight and let them come into you. Their army will be hit by the widow mines which will then force them to retreat with their army. And unless they speed boost away their medivacs, you can stim ahead and pick off their medivacs as they retreat.

Comment: I need to have more mines in my bio build in TvT! Seems stupid not to have any besides those that deny expos. Thanks, great answer!